# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when compiling in the terminal instead of compiling with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, vim, compiler-errors

I'm following the tutorial on classes of [the course on C++ of Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/free-learn-c-tutorial-beginners/learn/lecture/1747818#overview)  (up to minute 7:23)

Instead of `Eclipse` as an IDE, I'm using `Vim` as text editor and the terminal.

From the tutorial, I copied the 3 following text files:

`Classes.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void speak();

int main(){

    speak();

    return 0;
}
```

`Cat.h`:

```
#ifndef CAT_H_
#define CAT_H_

#endif
```

`Cat.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

void speak() {
    cout << "Meaouww !!!" << endl;
}
```

Then when running, `g++ Classes.cpp -o Classes` I get the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "speak()", referenced from:
      _main in ccA6NwIT.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `g++ Classes.cpp Cat.cpp -o Classes`

Comment: Many thanks @HolyBlackCat! Do you have some hinsight do understand what is happening behind the scene?

Comment: Do not focus on the bit about the architecture, focus on the undefined symbol, what that symbol was, and why it was unknown at that time.